# Mandarin Chinese and Antconc

Tags: corpora, software

Can [Antconc](http://www.laurenceanthony.net/software/antconc/) be used to build a corpus for Mandarin, Chinese?  Specifically, could characters be recognized, or if one were to upload a pinyin text, could tones be displayed?  Is this possible?